# how to get the value of a textbox inside a stackpanel, which is in turn a template in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Mytemplate in Listbox]

**I need that when you click on it, a file opens according to the name of Textbox 1**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding alignment}" MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" >
                                    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="{Binding alignment22}">
                                        <Border  Width="25" Height="25" CornerRadius="80" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="{Binding margin}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  >
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/чел.png"/>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid >
                                        <Border Style="{StaticResource MessageBorder}">
                                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                                                <Border DockPanel.Dock="{Binding alignment23}" Width="25" Height="25" CornerRadius="80" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <Border.Background>
                                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/pdficon.png"/>
                                                    </Border.Background>
                                                </Border>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" Name="escobar" Style="{StaticResource textboxtext}" />
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding s}" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="8" Margin="5,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource textboxdate}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
```

**The problem is that I do not know how to access a certain text field, it does not help to assign names to a certain text field, because they are not visible in the template**

```
private void StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ????
    }
```

**handler code**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" Name="escobar" Style="{StaticResource textboxtext}" />
```

**the value of the text field that should which should**

Comment: If you're using MVVM, the action might be invoked using an `ICommand` instead of using the `StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

Comment: the question is not this, but how to access the text field in the template in the mousedown event handler, with the name escobar, the delivery method is known to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name can be passed to the `FindName` method of the `StackPanel`:

```
private void StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)sender;
    TextBox escobar = stackPanel.FindName("escobar") as TextBox;
    if (escobar != null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void StackPanel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var model = (<YourDataClass>)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
    var theText = model.Text;
    ...
}
```